# Trying to interpolate JSX with a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I currently have my welcome message on my landing page setup as to only having "Hello" displayed until a user types their name in the modal. I would love to take the "Hello" away and have it appear with the user's name, after user clicks submit.

This is how it currently looks. 
[image]

After I enter my name in the modal, it looks like this:
[image]

I tried interpolating JSX with the string, but no luck.  Can somebody help?

This is how I have it in my render.

```
   <h1>{`Hello ${this.state.submitedFirstName && this.state.submitedFirstName}`}</h1>
```

Comment: Just set the default value of `submitedFirstName` to an empty string in the state.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you would like to show "Hello" and when user Mike has submitted his name, you would like to show only "Mike"? Or would you like to show "Hello Mike"?

Comment: @samdouble I would like to show "Hello Mike".  Right now, before user submits name, you only see "hello" on the landing page.  I want to remove that hello and show "Hello Mike" after user inputs their name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a conditional operator:

```
   <h1>{ this.state.submitedFirstName ? ` Hello ${this.state.submitedFirstName}` : ""}</h1>
```

If this.state.submitedFirstName is undefined or anything falsey (e.g. empty string "") it will return 'Hello Mike' or it will return an empty string.

You can also move the conditional outside so it doesn't even render the h1 tag unless there is a name.

```
{this.state.submitedFirstName && <h1>Hello {this.state.submitedFirstName}</h1>}
```

---

Here's an update to explain why the original code didn't work. I'll break it down into the order it gets executed and explain:

The state `this.state.submitedFirstName` starts as undefined. Therefore, when the code is first run the left side of the && (AND operator) evaluates to `undefined`. Because the && is not satisfied the left side is returned from the expression:

```js
console.log(this.state.submitedFirstName && this.state.submitedFirstName) // undefined (from the left side to be specific)
console.log(`${undefined}`) // "undefined" is converted to string 
console.log(`Hello ${undefined}`) // "Hello undefined"
```

After the state is set `this.state.submitedFirstName === "Mike"`. The left side "Mike" evaluates to truthy so it returns the right side which is also "Mike".

```
console.log(this.state.submitedFirstName && this.state.submitedFirstName) // "Mike" (from the right side to be specific)
// console.log(`Hello ${"Mike"}`) // "Hello Mike"
```

Thats why it either returns "Hello undefined" or "Hello Mike".

Check out [mdn for more info on the && and other logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: I tried using both of your suggestions, and it appears as I am getting an empty string. 

my state is submitedFirstName: ''

Comment: thank you. Do you know why my original solution was wrong? I would love to learn what mistake(s) I made in order to learn.

Comment: @csb00 Updated my answer with an explanation of why it wasn't working. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

That way, the render method will return null if this.state.submitedFirstName is null or undefined.

```
render() {
  const { submitedFirstName } = this.state;
  return (
    !!submitedFirstName
    && <h1>{`Hello ${submitedFirstName}`}</h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
<h1>Hello {YOUR_VARIABLE_HERE}</h1>
```

?